# PIL Python3 - How can I open a GIF file using Pillow?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

In my current condition, I can open an Image normally using a really short code like this

```
from PIL import Image

x = Image.open("Example.png")
x.show()
```

But I tried to use GIF format instead of png, It shows the file but it didn't load the frame of the GIF. Is there any possible way to make load it?

#### In My Current Code

```
from PIL import Image

a = Image.open("x.gif").convert("RGBA") # IF I don't convert it to RGBA, It will give me an error.
a.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Reading Sequences](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#image-sequences) in the documentation:

```
from PIL import Image

with Image.open("animation.gif") as im:
    im.seek(1)  # skip to the second frame

    try:
        while 1:
            im.seek(im.tell() + 1)
            # do something to im
    except EOFError:
        pass  # end of sequence
```

Comment: I've added my current code, is there anything wrong? because I tried the Documentation Example and it didn't go well.

Comment: Please try to be more precise. Your code shows loading a PNG, yet you said you have a GIF. Saying *"It didn't go well"* doesn't help very much when trying to debug - was there an error? Did you get a black image? What happens if you do `print(a)`? Can you share your image? Thank you.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, I was put the wrong format file but, I tried to print it as GIF format and it here's the output `<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=600x338 at 0x1946C8D0A90>`. Without the convert to RGBA, I got some error and it says `ValueError: cannot allocate more than 256 colors`.