# Can't duplicate .gif file in my folder. Will only give the first frame of the gif for each duplicate that is created

Tags: python, image, duplicates, python-imaging-library, gif

```
from PIL import Image

#Load the image
img = Image.open('1.gif')

for a in range(1,10):
    img.save(''+str(a)+'.gif')
```

Comment: Have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71747344/2836621

Comment: If copying complete, unaltered GIFs, use `shutil.copy()`

Comment: I haven't personally played with animated GIFs in Pillow; but the docs at https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving documents the "save_all" parameter: "If present and true, all frames of the image will be saved. If not, then only the first frame of a multiframe image will be saved."

Try "save_all=True".

If you're trying to get at individual frames, look into seek() (see "Reading sequences" in the same doc)

Comment: @MarkSetchell how would you write it? Just want to make sure I'm doing this right. I'm getting a bit confused on this one.

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. Are you trying to make 9 identical copies of an animated GIF? Or are you trying to extract 9 frames of one GIF into 9 separate files each containing one frame? Or something else?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm trying to make 9 identical copies of the animated gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to make 9 identical copies of `image.gif`, called `copy-1.gif` through `copy-9.gif` you don't need PIL/Pillow at all - you are just copying a file and the fact it contains an image is irrelevant, so you can simply use `shutil.copy`:

```
import shutil

# Make 9 copies of "image.gif"
for i in range(1,10):
    shutil.copy('image.gif', f'copy-{i}.gif')
```

If you list the results:

```
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff       2421 22 Jul 19:43 image.gif
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff       2421 22 Jul 19:43 copy-1.gif
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff       2421 22 Jul 19:43 copy-2.gif
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff       2421 22 Jul 19:43 copy-3.gif
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff       2421 22 Jul 19:43 copy-4.gif
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff       2421 22 Jul 19:43 copy-5.gif
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff       2421 22 Jul 19:43 copy-6.gif
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff       2421 22 Jul 19:43 copy-7.gif
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff       2421 22 Jul 19:43 copy-8.gif
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff       2421 22 Jul 19:43 copy-9.gif
```

Comment: You're a legend dude, worked perfectly. I really hope this helps out a lot more people that have been searching for the problem and have gotten hit with confusion.