# Python : seek() function from Pillow not working properly

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif, animated-gif

I am trying to extract all images from a 14 frames GIF of dancing characters
When I try using the seek() function from Pillow to go to the next frame and use show() on the object it always show me the same frame.
Here is my code :

```
image = Image.open(f"./characters/{key.decode('utf-8')}.gif")

image.show()
image.seek(1)
image.show()
```

Here are the results when I input the character 'a'
[Both showed frames for letter A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrOQ7.png).
And here is the full GIF
[Full 'A' GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSjxH.gif)

I tried using seek for every all of the 14 frames (0 to 13) and it still showed the same image.

I do not understand why it is not working, all help would be gladly appreciated !
If it is relevant I am developing using PyCharm

Comment: I think you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71747220/pil-python3-how-can-i-open-a-gif-file-using-pillow

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I downloaded your animated gif and using `seek` and `show` as you have worked fine for me.